# Почему добавлени объекта со свойствами в массив меняет предыдущие объекты и их свойства, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

я ввожу данные в оба инпута помещаю их в объект а объект в массив.

после этого меняю данные и и снова проделываю эту операцию после этого в массиве появляется два одинаковых объекта, хотя данные и отличались

а мне нужно было массив был такой:

```
[
  0:{
    "first-input": "vtrtr",
    "last-input": "brtbtr"
  },
  1:{
    "first-input": "45454",
    "last-input": "121212"
  },
]
```

вот сам пример:

```js
var myobjekt = {};
var myarray = [];
$('button').click(function() {
  myobjekt['first-input'] = $('input').eq(0).val();
  myobjekt['last-input'] = $('input').eq(1).val();
  myarray.push(myobjekt);
  console.log(myarray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button name="start">Пуск</button>
```

Comment: потому что у вас везде одна и та же ссылка на объект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myarray = [];
$('button').click(function() {
  var myobjekt = {
    'first-input': $('input').eq(0).val(),
    'last-input': $('input').eq(1).val()
  };
  myarray.push(myobjekt);
  console.log(myarray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button name="start">Пуск</button>
```